# How to configure Hadoop parameters on Amazon EMR?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hadoop2, emr, amazon-emr

I run a MR job with `one Master` and `two slavers` on the Amazon EMR, but got lots of the error messages like `running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 3.0 GB of 3 GB physical memory used; 3.7 GB of 15 GB virtual memory used. Killing container` after `map 100% reduce 35%`

I modified my codes by adding the following lines in the Hadoop 2.6.0 MR configuration, but I still got the same error messages.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "jobtest2");
//conf.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize","3073741824");                                                                   
conf.set("mapreduce.map.memory.mb", "8192");                                     
conf.set("mapreduce.map.java.opts", "-Xmx8192m");                                         
conf.set("mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb", "8192");                                         
conf.set("mapreduce.reduce.java.opts", "-Xmx8192m");
```

What is the correct way to configure those parameters(`mapreduce.map.memory.mb`, `mapreduce.map.java.opts`, `mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb`, `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts`) on Amazon EMR? Thank you!

Comment: have you tried changing these values in mapred-site.xml ??

Answer (score 3):

Hadoop 2.x allows you to set the map and reduce settings per job so you are setting the correct section. The problem is the Java opts Xmx memory must be less than the map/reduce.memory.mb.  This property represents the total memory for heap and off heap usage. Take a look at the defaults as an example: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-task-config.html. If Yarn was killing off the containers for exceeding the memory when using the default settings then this means you need to give more memory to the off heap portion, thus increasing the gap between Xmx and the total map/reduce.memory.mb.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html) for the AWS CLI.  There is a section on Hadoop and how to map to specific XML config files on EMR instance creation.  I have found this to be the best approach available on EMR.